# How to solve Flutter drawer showing Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

To be mentioned I'm new to both Flutter and Stackoverflow.

In my News reader app I have added a side drawer which pulls the news categories from an API using FutureBuilder. There is a `DrawerHeader` that contains the category named Popular News which is not fetched from the API, that is static.

Each time I'm opening the API, the Popular News category shows up and works fine but other categories do not show up rather in the console it shows an error like below.

```
I/flutter ( 4486): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4486): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter ( 4486): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 4486): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter ( 4486): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter ( 4486): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter ( 4486): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter ( 4486): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter ( 4486): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter ( 4486): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

My codes are given below

**The widget that returns the Drawer**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return SizedBox(
      width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*50,
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: const Color(0xFF2b4849)),
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child:  ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "Popular News",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 25
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => MostPopularNewsfeed(),
                        )
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: category,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.data == null) {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Loading",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _getDrawer(snapshot, index);
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**initState()** : This `category` is a `Future<List>`

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setState(() {
       category = fetchCategory();
    });
  }
```

**fetchCategory()** : This one fetches the categories from the API.

```
Future<List<Category>> fetchCategory() async {
    //try {
    String url = "https://tbsnews.net/json/category/news/list";
    dio.interceptors.add(DioCacheManager(CacheConfig(baseUrl: url)).interceptor);
    Response response = await Dio().get(url);
    print(response);

    List<Category> categoryList = [];
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = categoryDatabaseHelper.initDb();

    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decode = response.data;
      print(decode);
      for (var c in decode) {
        Category category = Category(c['tid'], c['name']);
        await categoryDatabaseHelper.insertCategory(category);
        categoryList.add(category);
      }
      return categoryList;
      //categoryDatabaseHelper.insertCategory(categoryList);
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to fetch category");
    }
  }
```

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried putting the `DrawerHeader` and `FutureBuilder` inside an `Expanded` widget instead of `ListView`. Did not work.

In the ListView I added `shrinkWrap: true`, also `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`. That was of no use either.

Tried to put them inside a `SizeBox` and `Column` widgets also. That did not work either.

The above are what I found by searching the previous questions related to this issue in StackOverflow. Lastly, I'm posting a question myself.

To be noted, when I take away that `DrawerHeader` everything starts working fine, no trouble then anymore. But this `DrawerHeader` has to be there.

Thank you very much for your time and sincere help.

Comment: try adding shrinkWrap: true and physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to your listview builder. because you are trying to build a listview inside a listview.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added both just now, but shows the same error again.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is only with the DrawerHeader try to wrap it with a `SizedBox` or a `ConstrainedBox` and give it a certain height and width.
The issue is that the `DrawerHeader` is not conststrained so the `ListView` while being built doesn't get to know its dimensions or constraints and throws this error.

This is my educated guess and let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: I have used both just now. SizeBox with some height and width according to the drawer size... then contrainedBox with minHeight and maxHeight ... all the same. ... But Thank you for your answer.